# Bounded holomorphic function uniformly continuous.

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Let $f:\{z\in\mathbb C\vert~ Re(z)>0\}\to\mathbb C$ be holomorphic and bounded. I would like to show that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\{z\in\mathbb C\vert~ Re(z) > c\}$ for each $c>0$ but I have no clue how to start. Any hints?

Comment: One idea is to prove $f'$ is bounded on each of those sets.

Comment: @zhw. Thanks! So far I could not manage to do that. Do you have another hint?

Comment: What do you know about estimating the size of derivatives of $f$  in complex analysis, given that you know something about the size of $f$?

Comment: @zhw. Oh my god, I'm stupid ;) The Cauchy-inequality.. Thank you very much. Sad that I can't accept your comment.